# Can I override Salesforce Sales Console Standard List View?

Tags: visualforce, console, custom-console-components

When list placement in Sales console is "Full screen, unpinned" I'd like to override the entire list view with a visualforce page.  Is this possible?

I'm also interested in anyone who has added a custom list view in a left sidebar custom console component.  I think StandardSetController may be a good way to accomplish this - your advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can't technically override the standard list view, but you can still accomplish what you are asking:

1. Create your Visualforce page you'd like to override the list view with.
2. Create a Visualforce Tab and name it the same thing as the object.
3. Add the newly created Visualforce Tab to your console app.

Voila!

You will need to ensure links are opened properly from your visualforce page.  To have a little more control, see the [Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/index.htm).

To answer your second question, a StandardSetController would work nicely.  To understand how custom console components work with data, refer to the same document.  Make use of Visualforce components if you will need similar functionality across a number of objects.

Comment: Thanks Bradley.  I got a nice left sidebar sortable list with angular.js  and I like it.  I am working through some filtering issues but I think that deserves another stack post :):)

Comment: I accomplished Bradley's suggestion by creating a VF page and a custom VF tab.  Then in the console app I added the tab to Navigation items.  I made this the only list available in the app and it basically provides the override  i was looking for.  You can make it full unpinned or left pinned, both work great.